# Python how to print tuple without quotes

Tags: python, tuples, snmp, quotes

I know that this is probably an easy question, but how do I remove the quotes produced by this code:

```
import netsnmp
site = "office"
session = netsnmp.Session( DestHost='10.0.0.250', Version=2, Community='public' )
mod = netsnmp.VarList( netsnmp.Varbind('HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrDeviceDescr.1') )
model = session.get(mod)
print model
```

This produces this output:

```
('HP Color LaserJet CM4540 MFP',)
```

How do I get rid of those parentheses and quote marks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
print model[0]
```

You're trying to the print the tuple representation.

Comment: A good rule of thumb when something isn't behaving as you expect is to check the type of the object. This problem would've been revealed immediately by a simple `print(type(model))`.